configure region for Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab runtime
When starting a runtime from https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws/, there does not seem to be any way to choose an AWS region. The URL of the studiolab that gets created (for me) looks like https://somehashcode.studio.us-east-2.sagemaker.aws/studiolab/default/jupyter/lab ... so apparently this one is running in us-east-2.
Can I make studiolab launch the runtime in us-west-2?
I need a specific region for a training which uses data from the NASA Earthdata Cloud, and because this is a training I am looking for a solution specifically for studiolab. I would not ask trainees to use the sagemaker console (i.e. they will only have their free studiolab accounts).

I don't think StudioLab supports choosing a region. Is it possible to duplicate the data to different regions? If not, you may have to try Notebook Instances or Studio notebooks (the ml.t3.medium is available as part of the free tier for 250 hours). You could provide them with the presigned URL that just gives your trainees access to the specific notebook.

Too bad, but thanks for confirming!
